# Automatically Receive Calls App on iPhone using Internet

Tags: iphone, call

I have been trying to find an app that does this on iPhone, but using internet not the phone service itself.

Closest Ive found was Skype, it has this feature on android and on any desktop but it lacks this on iPhone.

Is there any app like this available for iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this on an iPhone as Apple does not allow software to take over main-functions of an iPhone.

In the past (and it still probably is) it was possible to add BiteSMS to your iPhone after jailbreaking it. There might be a similar feature for phone calls, but it requires a jailbreak then.

So in short, **No,** Apple does not support this by default. You might be able to **bypass** this limit by jailbreaking your device and looking for a tweak which can do this for you.